# DIVs not making line breaks

Tags: html, css

I have two `div` elements next to each other in code, both set with `style="display:block;"` on them inline, and no other styling being applied (confirmed via DOM inspector).

There should be a line break between them, but for some reason I'm getting them rendering side by side.  Even putting a `br` tag between them only causes the second div to shift downward one line.

Code:

```
<div id="wkSched" style="display:block;">
    [...]
</div>
<br />
<div id="dSched" style="display:block;">
    [...]
</div>
```

Again, the DOM inspector showed both of them having display:block set, and not being overridden nor were there any other styles being applied.  with `block` being set, I shouldn't need the `br` at all, yet even with it there's still issues.  Also tried wrapping them in `p` tags as was suggested elsewhere, and that jank didn't work either.

Any clues about what is going on here?

EDIT: after being reminded of the `overflow` property in xionutz2k's answer, I went hunting for it.  One of the child elements in the first div had overflow set to auto, which was throwing my second container div out of position.  Thanks for the advice everyone.

Comment: Check the inspector again, some other style is being applied.

Comment: Can you reproduce this on jsFiddle.net?

Comment: By default, DIVs are already BLOCK elements.

Comment: your code is fine the problem must be elsewhere

Comment: What is the style of container that holds the divs?

Comment: Yuriy: also block.  Also set inline in case of something else trying to set it.

Comment: This question is unanswerable with the given info, please post more HTML

Comment: "Even putting a br tag between them only causes the second div to shift downward one line." I'd put my money on one of them being floated by some other CSS rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about editting the style to

```
style="display:block; clear:both; overflow:hidden;"
```

for both divs?

Comment: This got it.  I never think about `overflow`.

Comment: this is called a 'clearfix' hack and it's included in all the major CSS frameworks :)

Comment: the inline styles shouldn't be needed at all if you just have 2 divs. The main problem lies elsewhere, what is inside of your divs? and the styles for them. you probably have floating elements inside of the div or something like that

Comment: Huangism: you were correct.  The first div had a child element with overflow set to auto which was throwing things out of alignment.  After clearing that out, and removing the inline styles, things started appearing as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    position:relative; float:left;
```